# How to set input and output arrays while converting to a tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
   import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow.contrib import lite
   graph_def_file = 'D:\\Models\\kapl\\inference_graph   \\frozen_inference_graph.pb'
   input_arrays = [1,600,1024,1]  #image_tensor
    output_arrays = [1,600,1024,1]
    converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_def_file,     input_arrays, output_arrays)
    converter.post_training_quantize = True
    tflite_quantized_model = converter.convert()
open("quantized_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_quantized_model)
```

Comment: `input_tensor` and `output_tensor` are the lists of tensors which act as input and output to your model. They are mostly placeholder tensors.

Answer (score 0):

`input_arrays` and `output_arrays` denote the input & output tensors of the model graph.

The easiest way to inspect a graph from a `.pb` file is to use the
[summarize_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#inspecting-graphs) tool.

If that approach yields an error, you can visualize the GraphDef with [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) and look for the inputs and outputs in the graph. To visualize a `.pb` file, use the [`import_pb_to_tensorboard.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) script like below:

```
python import_pb_to_tensorboard.py --model_dir <model path> --log_dir <log dir path>
```